# Upload de imagem com vue.js + .net core 3.0

Tags: .net, vue.js, .net-core, vue.js-2, asp-net-core

Estou tentando fazer o upload de uma imagem, mas a imagem sempre chega como `null` em meu controller

Essa é minha ViewModel a qual recebo a imagem:

```
public class UpdateViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome é um campo obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Imagem")]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sobrenome é um campo obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Sobrenome")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telefone é um campo obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    //   [RegularExpression(@"^\([1-9]{2}\) [2-9][0-9]{3,4}\-[0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Celular está em um formato inválido.")]
    [Display(Name = "Celular")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Gênero")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

E esse é meu método Vue.js a qual envio a imagem:

```
updateGeneral: (name, surname, phoneNumber, gender, image) => {
let fd = new FormData()
fd.append('image', image)
fd.append('name', name)
fd.append('surname', surname)
fd.append('phoneNumber', phoneNumber)
fd.append('gender', gender)
return ApiService.put('/api/manage/update-general', fd )
  .then(res => {
    return res.data
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return Promise.reject(err.response.data)
  })
```

},

E assim que faço o upload:

```
<div>
      <div class="upload-img mr-4 sm:mb-0 mb-2">
        <input type="file" class="hidden" ref="uploadImgInput" @change="updateCurrImg($event)" accept="image/*">
        <vs-button @click="$refs.uploadImgInput.click()">{{ $t('UploadPhoto') }}</vs-button>
      </div>
      <p class="text-sm mt-2">{{ $t('AllowedExtensions') }} JPG {{ $t('Or') }} PNG. {{ $t('MaximumSize') }} 800kB</p>
    </div>

updateCurrImg(event) {
    this.avatarUrl = event.target.files[0]
  },
```

E aqui está o meu controller:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("update-general")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateGeneral([FromForm] UpdateGeneralViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        NotifyModelStateErrors();
        return Response(model);
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cade seu `controller`? Eu não tenho como testar, mas, o correto seria: `ApiService.put('/api/manage/update', file)` que é um `FormData` e você passar os outros campos para essa instância de `FormData`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic fiz algumas alterações e coloquei mais informações.

Comment: Eu fiz a correção e mandei um exemplo... observe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código parece que tem erro de digitação, porque no envio está `image` e na classe do C# está `File`, com tudo isso resolvi fazer um experimento minimo que na parte [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs):

```
updateGeneral() {
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("image", this.avatarUrl);
  fd.append("name", "name");
  fd.append("surname", "surname");
  fd.append("phoneNumber", "1836962585");
  fd.append("gender", "male");

  var myInit = {
    method: "PUT",
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "default",
    body: fd
  };
  fetch("http://localhost:62941/api/source/update-general", myInit)
    .then(c => c.json())
    .then(c => alert(c));
}
```

e no código da `API` do [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp):

`ViewModel`:

```
public class UpdateViewModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome é um campo obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
  [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
  [Display(Name = "Nome")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Imagem")]
  public IFormFile Image { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sobrenome é um campo obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
  [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
  [Display(Name = "Sobrenome")]
  public string Surname { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telefone é um campo obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]      
  [Display(Name = "Celular")]
  public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Gênero")]
  public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

---

`Controller`:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("update-general")]
public IActionResult UpdateGeneral([FromForm] UpdateViewModel model)
{
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
 {
    return BadRequest(model);
 }
 return Ok(new { status = 200, message = "Status Ok" });
}
```

também encontrei um problema no modelo com o nome errado. Tudo me leva a crer que seu projeto precisa verificar nome a nome porque os dois problemas eram isso.

Nesse exemplo foi feito o teste no servidor simulando tanto o comportamento do [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs) quanto do `back-end` [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp)